# how to create custom metrics in AWS ec2 for monitoring memory utilization of an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I would like to know how to create custom metrics to monitor my aws EC2 instance?
I want to monitor the memory utilization of my instance

I know its by creating custom metrics using power-shell but whenever i try it it says install .net SDK for the scripts i use .\mon-put-metrics-mem.ps1 for creating the custom metric.

need to know whether there is any settings or configurations while installing the aws .net SDK utility?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the SDK has changed

Change the following line:

$SDKLibraryLocation = dir C:\Windows\Assembly -Recurse -Filter "AWSSDK.dll"

to:

$SDKLibraryLocation = dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell" -Recurse -Filter "AWSSDK.dll"